# Mysql each row fetch along with data from other table

Tags: mysql, node.js, q, yield

I am trying to write a code for fetching data 2 mysql table by a primary key and foreign key solution

What could be the best solution to write sync code to fetch the data.
I have tried to use Q promises and other methods.

These are my options

- Async
- Q
- Yield
- Generators

Please do let me know if there are better option to write nodejs async code to sync code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a NodeJS system, actual synchronous code would be a huge performance bottleneck as it would block any other processing while the IO takes place.

I find that promises "look" a little more synchronous in code than callbacks, even when using a library like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async). There are some other benefits to promises as well.

A library like [knex](https://knexjs.org), [bookshelf](https://bookshelfjs.org) or [sequelize](https://sequelizejs.com) might make your life easier when working with with SQL and those have promises built in to get you started.

Comment: I decided to use promises for my job. And they work just as how i would expect them. I found lib Q to be very helpful. Thanks.